# How to make solid color for databar in apache.poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to create a sheet with progress bar which will represent some progress.

I'm using these libraries:

1. `org.apache.poi:poi:4.1.0`
2. `org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.1.0`
3. `org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:4.1.0`

All I get is a progress bar with gradient, but I need a progress bar with solid color instead color scale.

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's hard to spot what you're doing wrong!

Comment: Are you talking about data bars of conditional formatting? If so, then `apache poi` does not support what you wants. All conditional formatting data bars defined in `Office Open XML` are using gradient colors. There is not even a attribute or property to change that. Later `Excel` versions are using extensions from namespace `x14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main"`. But those are not part of the `Ecma Office Open XML File Formats Standard`.

Comment: @Gagravarr i'm sorry, but code is not neccesary for the question. I'm asking about possibility of apache.poi to work with formatting of data bar

Comment: @AxelRichter this is bad, because i realy need to set solid color. So, if it isn't possible to make it with `apache.poi`, can you suggest any other libraires or by java reflection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All conditional formatting data bars defined in `Office Open XML` are using gradient colors. There is not even a attribute or property to change that. Later `Excel` versions are using extensions from namespace `x14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main"`. But those are not part of the `Ecma Office Open XML File Formats Standard`.

`Apache poi` until now only bases on `Ecma Office Open XML File Formats Standard`. So the only way to make solid color for conditional formatting data bar in `apache poi` is creating the `XML` of the extended `x14` data bar conditional formatting from scratch.

Complete example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDataBarFormatting;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFConditionalFormattingRule;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class ConditionalFormattingDataBars {

 public static void applyDataBars(SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF, String region, ExtendedColor color) throws Exception {
  CellRangeAddress[] regions = { CellRangeAddress.valueOf(region) };
  ConditionalFormattingRule rule = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule(color);
  DataBarFormatting dbf = rule.getDataBarFormatting();
  dbf.getMinThreshold().setRangeType(ConditionalFormattingThreshold.RangeType.NUMBER);
  dbf.getMinThreshold().setValue(0d);
  dbf.getMaxThreshold().setRangeType(ConditionalFormattingThreshold.RangeType.NUMBER);
  dbf.getMaxThreshold().setValue(100d);

  dbf.setIconOnly(true);

  dbf.setWidthMin(0); //cannot work for XSSFDataBarFormatting, see https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_0_1/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFDataBarFormatting.java?view=markup#l57
  dbf.setWidthMax(100); //cannot work for XSSFDataBarFormatting, see https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_0_1/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFDataBarFormatting.java?view=markup#l64

  if (dbf instanceof XSSFDataBarFormatting) {
   Field _databar = XSSFDataBarFormatting.class.getDeclaredField("_databar");
   _databar.setAccessible(true);
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTDataBar ctDataBar =
    (org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTDataBar)_databar.get(dbf);
   ctDataBar.setMinLength(0);
   ctDataBar.setMaxLength(100);
  }

  // use extension from x14 namespace to set data bars not using gradient color 
  if (rule instanceof XSSFConditionalFormattingRule) {
   Field _cfRule = XSSFConditionalFormattingRule.class.getDeclaredField("_cfRule");
   _cfRule.setAccessible(true);
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCfRule ctRule =
    (org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCfRule)_cfRule.get(rule);
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTExtensionList extList =
    ctRule.addNewExtLst();
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTExtension ext = extList.addNewExt();
   String extXML = 
      "<x14:id"
    + " xmlns:x14=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main\">"
    + "{00000000-000E-0000-0000-000001000000}"
    + "</x14:id>";
   org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject xlmObject = org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject.Factory.parse(extXML);
   ext.set(xlmObject);
   ext.setUri("{B025F937-C7B1-47D3-B67F-A62EFF666E3E}");

   Field _sh = XSSFConditionalFormattingRule.class.getDeclaredField("_sh");
   _sh.setAccessible(true);
   XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet)_sh.get(rule);
   extList = sheet.getCTWorksheet().addNewExtLst();
   ext = extList.addNewExt();
   extXML = 
      "<x14:conditionalFormattings xmlns:x14=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main\">"
    + "<x14:conditionalFormatting xmlns:xm=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/excel/2006/main\">"
    + "<x14:cfRule type=\"dataBar\" id=\"{00000000-000E-0000-0000-000001000000}\">"
    + "<x14:dataBar minLength=\"" + 0 + "\" maxLength=\"" + 100 + "\" gradient=\"" + false + "\">"
    + "<x14:cfvo type=\"num\"><xm:f>" + 0 + "</xm:f></x14:cfvo>"
    + "<x14:cfvo type=\"num\"><xm:f>" + 100 + "</xm:f></x14:cfvo>"
    + "</x14:dataBar>"
    + "</x14:cfRule>"
    + "<xm:sqref>" + region + "</xm:sqref>"
    + "</x14:conditionalFormatting>"
    + "</x14:conditionalFormattings>";
   xlmObject = org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject.Factory.parse(extXML);
   ext.set(xlmObject);
   ext.setUri("{78C0D931-6437-407d-A8EE-F0AAD7539E65}");
  }

  sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions, rule);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("new sheet");

  double[] list = new double[]{0d, 10d, 20d, 30d, 40d, 50d, 60d, 70d, 80d, 90d, 100d};
  for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
   sheet.createRow(i+1).createCell(0).setCellValue(0d);
   sheet.getRow(i+1).createCell(1).setCellValue(list[i]);
   sheet.getRow(i+1).createCell(2).setCellValue(100d);
  }

  SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();
  ExtendedColor color = workbook.getCreationHelper().createExtendedColor();
  color.setARGBHex("FF80C279");
  applyDataBars(sheetCF, "B2:B12", color);

  sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 50*256);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("ConditionalFormattingDataBars.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

This code will only work properly always for new created `XSSFWorkbook`. If the `XSSFWorkbook` was created from an existing workbook, the this could contain `org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTExtensionList` for `x14` extensions already. If so, then these must be taken into account. But that would be a much more complex and challenging project.